# How can I submit WPForm Elementor to my email?

Tags: wordpress, elementor, wpforms

Hi I have designed my website on Elementor and the only thing left is the cotact form

[wpforms id="1287"]
e

This is the only code i have for the contact form and I want it to send the NAME, NUMBER, EMAIL and MESSAGE on to my email (rk_ali@outlook.com)
https://sawat.co.uk/index.php/contact/

Assistance please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What do you need assistance with exactly?

You need to configure the contact form from WPforms itself.

and then insert [wpforms id="1287"] in a shortcode widget.